# mysql not respecting wait_timeout setting in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, mysql2

I've set a wait_timeout in my.cnf and restarted the server, but the time on idle connections continues to grow larger than the default 100s I set. Any ideas why this is happening?

PS: I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and Mysql Server 5.5. Using Rails 3 with the mysql2 gem.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 20;
+------+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+------+
| ID   | USER             | HOST                                | DB                       | COMMAND | TIME | STATE | INFO |
+------+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+------+

|  760 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:45852 | x | Sleep   | 4202 |       | NULL |
|  912 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:40929 | y  | Sleep   | 4194 |       | NULL |
|  976 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:40970 | y  | Sleep   | 4193 |       | NULL |
|  836 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:49903   | z | Sleep   | 4189 |       | NULL |
| 1743 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:44585  | z | Sleep   | 4157 |       | NULL |
| 1778 | user | ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:48714    | a  | Sleep   | 4154 |       | NULL |
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the problem is in the mysql2 gem. [It does this really awesome thing](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6441) ...

Essentially it substitutes a default wait_timeout value of about 25 days (2147483s) of its own as the wait_timeout value (probably the session version of wait_timeout) that the connection uses, basically overriding whatever setting we specify on the server.

By setting a **wait_timeout: value** in config/database.yml the timeout works as it should. When the connection gets killed, however, you get  "mysql server has gone away" errors.

By specifying an accompanying **reconnect: true**
option in database.yml, everytime the connection is reused the connection's timer is reset, BUT after that it uses the GLOBAL wait_timeout setting from mysql directly

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the `wait_timeout` for a session is being set as the value of the `interactive_timeout` system variable.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'interactive_timeout'
```

And the default value for that is 8 hours.

Comment: I thought so too, but on another box (same config, I manually edited the one above down to 100), interactive timeout is 28800 but I'm seeing sleeping processes 190584s old :\